# ssh tunneling oddness

Tags: ssh-tunnel

*This example is related to MongoDB but the core issue is with SSH tunneling, MongoDB stuff should add value though*

Hi,

I'm attempting to bring up a local MongoDB node which is part of a ReplicaSet based in a data-centre. TCP/IP will be tunneled over SSH from local to data-centre.

All boxes, local and data-centre, are running CentOS.

This works fine when creating a tunnel on data-centre box1 to local node using:

```
ssh -v -4 -f -N -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -L27017:127.0.0.1:27017 -g a_user@server_i_have_ssh_access_to
```

box1 can access the local node Mongo shell with command (**cmd 1**):

```
mongo --host localhost --port 27017
```

box2 can also access the local node Mongo shell with command (**cmd 2**):

```
mongo --host box1 --port 27017
```

box2 in the data-centre can also connect to the box1:27017, the forwarded port of my local node.

however, it would be much preferable, simpler, and should be possible to setup a reverse forward between local node and box1 on the same ports as above. Using the command:

```
ssh -v -4 -f -N -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -R27017:127.0.0.1:27017 -g a_user@box1
```

now i can connect from box1 to local node using **cmd 1** above, however, **cmd 2** fails with:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server box1:27017} (anon):1139 exception: connect failed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `-R` only listens on the loopback interface (the default for `-L` is all interfaces). Hence cmd1 works because it is being run locally on box1 but cmd2 fails because it is being run on box2. The fix is to change `-R` to one of:

```
-R:27017:127.0.0.1:27017
-R'*:27017:127.0.0.1:27017'
```

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is TCP Wrappers or some other authentication is failing. Anything in `/var/log/auth.log` if it's a Debian-based OS or similar ?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using CentOS.The equivalent log is located at /var/log/secure, and there are no related messages in this log on any of the related machines.